# c# Linq reference unable to load

Tags: c#, linq, .net-3.5

Im unable to add a reference to System.Data.Linq to my project, I get the following error

> The referenced component
>   'System.Data.Linq' could not be found.

Even though i added it through the Add reference screen and my other projects add it without issue. This is how it looks in my project

[image: Failed Load]

And this is how it appears in my other project using the same reference

[image: Added Fine]

Any ideas why this happens, both projects us framework 3.5

Thanks
Sp

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is it possible that the failing one is set to the "client-only profile" of .NET 3.5?